# sonata color the fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

I am trying to understand how Sonata works and I have a question. I saw something nice about their demo and I can not find in their documentation like to do. Maybe you can help me.

In the fields they arrive to color values according to criteria surely of the value of the latter I would like to know how to do. I put a small screen that I took on their site that help you maybe to understand my request.
[image: Colorful fields]

I have a small form which I also put the code and I would like to be able to color in green the "client" in red "ex-client" and in blue "prospect" how am I supposed to do?

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->tab('General Information',array('class'=>'col-md-9'))
        ->with('', array('class'=>'col-md-9'))
        ->add('firstName', 'text')
        ->add('surname', 'text')
        ->add('address', 'text',array('required'=> false))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'required' => false))
        ->add('Phone', 'text', array(
            'required' => false))
        ->add('birthdate', 'birthday', array('label' => 'Date of Birth','required'=>false))
        ->end()
        ->with('Others Informations',array('class'=>'col-md-3'))
        ->add('Status', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Client' => 'Client',
                'Ex-Client' => 'Ex-Client',
                'Prospect' => 'Prospect'),
        ))
        ->add('businessname', 'text', array('label' => 'Business Name','required'=>false))
        ->add('typeofbusiness', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Blank' => Null,
                'SE' => 'SE',
                'SA' => 'SA',
                'LLP' => 'LLP',
                'LTD' => 'LTD',
                'Payroll' => 'Payroll'),
            'label' => 'Type of buisness'
        ))
        ->end()
        ->end()
        ->tab('Comment',array('class'=>'col-md-12'))
        ->add('comments', 'textarea', array('required'=>false))
        ->end()
    ;
}



protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('surname')
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('address')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('birthdate', null, array(
            'label' => 'Date of birth (mm/dd/yyyy)'), 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
            'format'                => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
            'dp_side_by_side'       => true,
            'dp_use_current'        => false,
            'dp_use_seconds'        => false,
        ))
        ->add('status')
        ->add('businessname')
        ->add('typeofbusiness')
        ->add('comments')
    ;

}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('surname')
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('address')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('birthdate')
        ->add('Status')
        ->add('businessname')
        ->add('typeofbusiness')
        ->add('comments');
}

public function toString($object)
{
    return $object instanceof Client
        ? $object->getSurname()
        : 'Client'; // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
}
```

}

Also in the installation and grip they make us create a BlogPost but nowhere I have defined anything and the boolean values are in red or green. I really do not understand how to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom template for your field(s)

See here : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-template

Comment: ` {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <div>
        <p class="ClientStatus">{{ object.Status }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}`       I did that and trying to create a class into a css file but it's not working. :/ Only the "title" of the column change to be black now and i can't click on it any more to order my column

Comment: Also as I do not understand why I have nothing of all that to do for the booleans who are already coloring themselves ...

Comment: I foud a way to do it. Thx your answer was helpfull